# Can't directly access page with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I use react-router-dom and create-react-app to make my project.
I found that I can't directly enter the link to go to that page like 'https://xxx/about',

It will throw Page not found. I can just go to index and use the navbar to link to another page.

My website link:
https://telegramgroups.pinkjelly.org/

I can use this link to enter index.html.
But I can't go to other path by link
https://telegramgroups.pinkjelly.org/interest

My code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div>Telegram Groups</div>
          <a
            className="github"
            target="_blank"
            href="https://github.com/catsheue/telegram-group"
          >
            Github
          </a>
        </header>

        <div className="App-body">
          <nav className="App-nav">
            <ul>
              {pathList.map((item) => {
                const id = nanoid();
                const { path, name } = item;
                return (
                  <li key={id}>
                    <NavLink to={path}>{name}</NavLink>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div className="App-content">
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/chatroom">
                <ListSection list={chatList} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <div className="App-hello">
                  收藏一些telegram群組，有想要加入的話歡迎來信
                  catsheue@gmail.com，或
                  <a href="https://t.me/lunajs" className="App-link">
                    私我telegram
                  </a>
                </div>
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

My github:
https://github.com/catsheue/telegram-group

My react-router version:
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

I tried googled but can't figure out which one is my scenario.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you elaborate more, what exactly is the issue it is hard to understand.

Comment: So whenever you try to hit a specific route from the address bar it returns not found. It is not the problem in the above snippet. It is about how your server is running. Your server should return index html for all the routes which are not mapped for any api.

Comment: Configurations your production server for client side routing
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

Comment: Perhaps add a `[...].html` suffix to both your route path as well as the direct URL? Your components will ultimately bundle to an HTML file, that could be why your route is not landing.

Comment: Thanks.
I look at create-react-app docs and  add a file .htaccess, it solved my problem !! Thanks a million @TauseefAhmad

Comment: any solution for this